# How to get the randrange equivalent of python in Ruby

Tags: ruby, random

I want to get a random value between 0 and 20 but skips by 3, like the python equivalent of:

```
random.randrange(0,20, 3)
```

Comment: More generically, `rand((upper - lower) / skip).to_i * skip + lower`. If you don't have skip, then `rand(lower...upper)` works. All of these assume you don't include `upper`.

Comment: thanks @bjhaid can you explain why the number 20 when divided doesnt give a float value

Comment: Because both numbers are integers. `20 / 3 == 6`; `20.0 / 3 == 6.666...`; `20 / 3.0 == 6.666...` - exactly the same as in Python2.

Comment: Integer division would always return an integer, one or both of them has to be a float to return a float

Comment: `0.step(20.pred, 3).to_a.sample` or `(0...20).step(3).to_a.sample`

Comment: @bjhaid @Amadan: Both don't return 18 (assuming `upper` is `20`).

Comment: @cremno why do you have `.pred` in your first example? You shouldn't need that. I edited my answer using yours in my method. I'm surprised no one else upvoted your comment as it is really the most elegant.

Comment: @Beartech: Because the range is exclusive.

Comment: @cremno aha! I get it. I didn't realize the Python randrange excluded the upper limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
(0...20).to_a.keep_if {|z| z % 3 == 0}.sample
```

And bjhaid's example will work if you make the top number the first number that is equal or greater that is divisible by 3, i.e.:

```
rand(21 / 3) * 3
```

But you would have to manually set that upper number depending on what your slice size and upper number are.

My one-liner is kind of ugly to me, if I were using it in just one place in an entire program I might use it. but if I was going to re-use it I'd make a method: **edit** I just noticed @cremno answer in the comments. I like their `step` version better than mine. I'd use that in a method:

```
def randrange(lower, upper, grouping)
  (lower...upper).step(grouping).to_a.sample
end
```

my old method...

```
def randrange(lower, upper, grouping)
  arr = (lower...upper).to_a.keep_if {|i| i % grouping == 0}
  arr.sample
end
```